# Eval method don't save results after postback

Tags: .net, webforms, web-controls

I'm trying to fix bug in a legacy project on WEB FORMS (.Net 4).
I have some logic at Layout.master (layout for pages) that use control like this:

```
<uc4:FooterCharity ID="NewsItemUserControl1" DataSource="<%#Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" />
```

and this control use Eval() like this:

```
<li class="footer__sponsor-item carousel-block">
    <a href="/sponsory/<%# Eval("PathInfo")%>/">
        <img src="<%# Eval("Image")%>" style="width: 198px; height: 148px;"/>
    </a>
</li>
```

And on the page i use some other control that sends postback (submit button).

*The problem that after reload page there is the same html with all rendered controls, but **without results of Eval()** function*

html before postback:

```
<li class="footer__sponsor-item carousel-block">
    <a href="/sponsory/rossijskaja-futbolnaja-premier-liga/">
        <img src="/img/Sponsors/rfpl.png" style="width: 198px; height: 148px;">
    </a>
</li>
```

html after postback:

```
<li class="footer__sponsor-item carousel-block">
    <a href="/sponsory//">
        <img src="" style="width: 198px; height: 148px;">
    </a>
</li>
```

How can i fix this problem?

Can i save results of Eval() with other html or can i re-render it?

**UPD**:
Data for controls gets here:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="true">
                                    <LayoutTemplate>
                                        <ul class='footer__sponsor-list'>
                                            <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" class="footer__sponsor-item" />
                                        </ul>
                                    </LayoutTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    <uc4:FooterCharity ID="NewsItemUserControl1" DataSource="<%#Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                                    <uc4:FooterCharity ID="NewsItemUserControl1" DataSource="<%#Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" />
                                </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                            </asp:ListView>
...
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" TypeName="LigaStavokShops.DataAccessObject.SponsorMapper" SelectMethod="GetSponsors"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

If i put breakpoint, i see that it called once - at first page load, but not after postback (render of control and GetSponsors both)

**UPD2**:
Post data:

```
 <asp:Button ID="SubmitVacancyFormImageButton" class="questionary___submit" CausesValidation="true" Text="Отправить анкету" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitVacancyFormImageButton_Click" />
```

Comment: What is populating that control with data?  Is that operation not being performed on that particular postback?

Comment: "What is populating that control with data?" - few text fields and one file from user

Comment: Can you be more specific?  In code, where/how specifically is that data being applied to that control?  Does that same operation happen on postback?  Where does `DataSource="<%#Container.DataItem %>"` get its data?

Comment: updated post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my solve of problem is to call **ListView.DataBind** on page load:

```
<body>
    <%= ListView1.DataReBind()%>
```

and extension class is:

```
public static class ObjectDataSourceHelper
    {
        public static string DataReBind(this ListView lv)
        {
            lv.DataBind();
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```